# Add a button to scroll me to my answer if I view a question which I have previously answered

Tags: feature-request, answers, information-display, navigation

If I open a question that I have already answered, it would be nice if there was an icon or link telling me something along the lines of "You have posted an answer to this question." This would scroll me directly to my answer and let me reuse that information.

For example, this could look like:

[image: A green circular button in the topbar next to the user profile picture]

A while ago I worked on some thing and posted an answer, but after a long time I am now searching for it again and checking the answers but unfortunately I cannot find it. It would be nice if there was an indication that I posted an answer at the top of the page!

Note: I know I can view answers I've posted in my user profile, but it can still be difficult to find the answers I'm looking for, as I might have posted a lot of answers!

---

Now a days browsers are providing this feature. as if we search some thing/text. Then if the text matches in the already opened browser-window-tabs then it shows **`Switch to tab`**. As show in below image.

[image]

In this way `Switch to Own Answer` if added in StackOverflow that will good i guess.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, isn't this already implemented? You can go to [your profile's Answers tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5081877/yash?tab=answers) and any link there is directly to your answer to that certain question.

Comment: Potential edge case exists when one has posted multiple answers to a specific question. This happens especially on meta sites as well as some main sites such as Puzzling and Code Golf.

Comment: If someone could utilize this search `inquestion:[questionID] user:me` and make it into a userscript...

Comment: @MAR User profile displaying posts are different form my question.

Comment: @`Sonic the Introverted Hedgehog ` as you said if multiple answers are written by user then you may navigate to most recent answer.

Comment: @M.A.R.ಠ_ಠ If you come across a question you've answered and want to find your answer to it, you'd have to go to your own user profile, go to the Answers tab, find the question title in the list, and click on it. It's useful to have a button that removes these tedious steps entirely.

Comment: Can you people understand the post before giving down-vote.

Comment: What makes you think people don't understand the post?  There's many reasons to downvote on Meta, one of which is disagreement.

Comment: @fbueckert As they are saying, user profile contains information. But my question is not related to it.

Comment: And, again, what proof do you have of A) who downvoted, and B) why they did so?  You think it's for a specific reason, which is likely very incorrect.

Comment: @fbueckert When i posted the question thier are lot of answers, related to user profile. that is the gues, So i informing them at that time. Not right now. Could you see the above comments, answer to this post were deleted.

Comment: So you don't know why.  That's fine; that's how the system is designed to work.  But you're not helping yourself by assuming people don't understand; that comment doesn't help you, as it looks more antagonistic than open minded to critique.  It's not constructive to try to strawman criticism, as it doesn't show receptiveness to disagreement.

Comment: @fbueckert Why you are thinking that comment doesn't help me, i know the commented information and dont justify that i dont respect the down-voters.

Comment: Because it doesn't.  There are more voters than commentors.  If you want to leave it, well, it's your question.  But it won't help you gain a receptive audience.

Comment: A better comment would be, "it would be great if I knew why others are disagreeing with this idea, so that I can improve it to address concerns".

Answer (score 4):

This feature would probably be used by too few people to be implemented natively by the team.

However I've made a userscript you can install that adds this feature. [Install it here](https://gist.github.com/shu8/1047244d44ab68b843ca84046f2ee021/raw/ca4b2daeee4db308f7fb378d0512cc9114a4189d/own-answer-hint.user.js) or [view the source here](https://gist.github.com/shu8/1047244d44ab68b843ca84046f2ee021). You'll need to install a userscript manager like Tampermonkey first ([Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en), [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/tampermonkey/), [Other browsers](https://tampermonkey.net/)).

Here's what it looks like:

> [image: 'You have previously answered this question' at the top of the page]